# Find Text in Microsoft Word And Replace With Java String Array

Tags: java, replace, ms-word, apache-poi

I am attempting to find the value `$beta` in my word doc and replace with an array of data from my java program.  The data that I want to replace with is
.......

```
Blue - 33 - 100
Blue - 28 - 75
Blue - 30 - 90
```

I verify this is accurate by using the print statement in the syntax below.  However, when I open my word document after code saves it, **ONLY** the last value `Blue - 30 - 90` is in the word document, not all 3 stacked on each other like I have in my code post above.

Just like my example above this is how I want the code to appear in the word document when replaced with the java syntax.  How should the code read to make that happen?

```
public static void Test() {
    String valuetowrite = null;
    for (SPData data : qryresults) {
        valuetowrite = String.join("\r\n", data.toString());
        System.out.println(valuetowrite);
    }
    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(SOURCE_FILE));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    if (text != null) {
                        if (text.contains("$beta")) {
                            text = text.replace("$beta", valuetowrite);
                            r.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I follow code suggestion in the answer and use the below syntax which on the JAVA side of things, has the data print as desired, but once it is in word, all the data is on one line, not each on an individual line like I desire

```
String valuetowrite = "";
for (SPData data : qryresults) {
  valuetowrite = valuetowrite + String.join("\r\n", data.toString());
}
System.out.println(valuetowrite);
```

Comment: Word does not understand \r\n - see thread here to see if it can help you out at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495701/retain-newline-in-word-file-generation-using-apache-poi

Comment: I am writing an List of data to word at one time, so I am not able to add in a new paragraph like the ink you posted suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it is using `r.addBreak();` which will add in a line break like you want.

```
private static void WriteToWordWithLineBreak() {
    ArrayList<String> datatowrite = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (SPData data : qryresults) {
        datatowrite.add(data.toString());
    }
    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(SOURCE_FILE));
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            System.out.println("Found paragraph "+p);
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                    String text = r.getText(0);
                    if (text != null) {
                        if (text.contains("$beta")) {
                            r.setText(datatowrite.get(0), 0);
                            for (int i=1; i < datatowrite.size(); i++){
                                r.addBreak();
                                r.setText(datatowrite.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        doc.write(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String valuetowrite = "";
for (SPData data : qryresults) {
    valuetowrite = valuetowrite + String.join("\r\n", data.toString());
}
System.out.println(valuetowrite);
```